# MS SQL 2005(2008) Кубический корень из отрицательного числа

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо извлечь кубический корень из отрицательного числа. Пишу:

```
select POWER (-8.0, 1.0/3.0)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Сообщение 3623, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 1 Ошибка домена.

**Есть специальная функция или какой-то способ?**

Можно конечно в лоб:

```
declare @x float
set @x = -8.0
select POWER (ABS(@x), 1.0/3.0) * @x / ABS(@x)
```

Comment: С нулём будут проблемы. Лучше так:

select sign(-8)*power (abs(-8.0), 1.0/3.0)